# codeigniter - how to query two varibles in two tables and join?

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, join

I'm really not good at sql.

This situation is i want to search an data that in two tables.

This is my model.

```
public function get_commission_week($username, $weekId){

    $this->db->select('mc.clientId, mc.account,cb.weekId,cb.create_at');

    $this->db->from('tb_member_client mc', 'tb_commission_bonus cb');

    $this->db->where('mc.account', $username);
    $this->db->where('cb.weekId', $weekId);

    $this->db->join('tb_commission_bonus cb', 'cb.clientId = mc.clientId');

    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result()->$row;

}
```

How to make a sql search to an array that have related data of this username of this week?

Comment: change this **$this->db->from('tb_member_client mc', 'tb_commission_bonus cb');** to this **$this->db->from('tb_member_client mc');**

Comment: $this->db->join('tb_commission_bonus cb', 'cb.clientId = mc.clientId'); if you don't specify any 3'rd parameter, it will set as INNER join by default.

Comment: check roytuts.com/codeigniter-join-example/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function get_commission_week($username, $weekId){

    $this->db->select('mc.clientId, mc.account,cb.weekId,cb.create_at');

    $this->db->from('tb_member_client mc');

    $this->db->where('mc.account', $username);
    $this->db->where('cb.weekId', $weekId);

    $this->db->join('tb_commission_bonus cb', 'cb.clientId = mc.clientId','left');

    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result()->$row;

}
```